# What does "no crickets" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have had a quick first talk with a company at which I have applied for remote work and I kept browsing their website when I came across this:

> Supportive. Friendly. Being there for one another. No crickets when asking for help.

[Source and context](https://pub.clevertech.biz/is-the-8-hours-work-day-a-lie-500448a261b3)

In that section of the blog article, the writer is talking about the values of the company.

What does "no crickets" mean in this context? Is it a common phrase? I haven't found it in TheFreeDictionary.com or dictionary.com. The closer entry I found was:

> (informal) not cricket, not fair play

I understand the sentence, because of the context, as conveying the idea that there should be no avoiding helping others. But the exact meaning of "No crickets when asking for help" evades me. "Don't be shy when asking for help"? "Do not hesitate to ask for help?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["Crickets"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=%2Acrickets%2A) is a kind of auditory idiom that means "no response".  The reference is to "the sound of [crickets](https://images2.onionstatic.com/clickhole/3356/1/16x9/600.jpg) chirping," as in, "very peaceful, not a single voice to disturb the tranquility".

So in your example, the speaker is making a comparison to other work environments where he would get no response when asking a question.

Another example:

> I got up on stage and started my comedy routine, but after my first joke, nothing but *crickets*.  It was not a good time.

Here, "crickets" means that the comedian didn't get any laughs from the audience, or possibly any response at all.  Not a good thing when you're trying to be funny.

Alternately, instead of saying "crickets" you can make the actual sound of crickets chirping to mean the same thing.